# Observable.first().subscribe() in place of Promise.then()

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a variety of methods which I recently converted from returning promises to returning observables. Currently, these methods usually only return a single value. So, where I used to call `myMethod.then()`, I switched to `myMethod.first().subscribe()`. I did this instead of just `subscribe()`, because I'm hoping to have the observable and subscription automatically complete and clean up. Is my understanding of this correct, and is this a reasonable approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your former promise now is an observable which completes after emitting its value you should not have to add the `.first()` for lifecycle cleanup. That is merely a modifier of your observable to signal intent to future you (or a coworker) that you expect exactly one value from the invoked observable and the code will error otherwise.

Comment: You can use [single](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-single) instead of ```first``` to actually get an error if the observable doesn't produce a result.

Comment: That makes sense. So, adding `take(1)` before calling `mergeMap()` on the observable would handle the cleanup and the client can just subscribe and never worry about unsubscribing etc? Edit: in this example, `myMethod()` uses `mergeMap()` internally and returns the resulting observable.

Comment: Its more of defense then need. When your `mergeMap()` receives a completion from upstream everything will clean itself up. If it receives `0`,`1` or `n` values those will all go through the `mergeMap()` and be emitted by the `myMethod()` returned Observable before completing itself.

Comment: @Brandon Depending on usecase you might want to use either: [`single()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-single) will error if the observable emits 0 or more then 1 value. [`first()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-first) will error if the observable emits 0 values. Difference is also that `first()` completes after first emission where `single` will wait till completion to make sure only 1 element is emitted